# Exception while appending the deserialized output of json in a file

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-web-api, json.net

**Scenario:**

I am calling a Web API from a console application which has image(s) as input. The output is in JSON format which I have de-serialized.

```
static void Main()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test\Images");
    var extensions = new[] { "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg" };     
    var files = extensions.SelectMany(ext => di.GetFiles(ext));

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string imageFilePath = file.FullName;
             // Execute the REST API call.
            MakeAnalysisRequest(imageFilePath);
        }        
}

static async void MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath)
{
    //logic - request response Web API
    //.....
    string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(JsonPrint(contentString,imageFilePath);
}

static string JsonPrint(string contentString,string imageFilePath)
{
    //sb is the json string
     dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sb.ToString());
     var anger = obj[0].faceAttributes.emotion.anger;
     var happy = obj[0].faceAttributes.emotion.happy;

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append("Anger = " +anger);
        str.Append("Happy = "+happy);

        string path = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Face.txt";
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        tw.WriteLine(str.ToString());
        tw.Close();

return str.ToString();
}
```

**Issue:**
If the input is a single image, then there is no exception. But for multiple files, I get the following exception:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Desktop\Face.txt' because it is being used by another
>   process.'

**Note:**

If there are 10 images as an input, and if the exception occurs *after* 2 or 3 images are called, then the data of these few files are stored in the file.

Comment: Find your anti-virus software and see if you can exclude the target folder. You should probably pick something else than the Desktop for that.

Comment: Get used to the `using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true)) { }` pattern. Will save you a lot of frustration.

Comment: Your requests are all writing to the same file before each previous call finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown as expected since you access the same file by at the same time by multiple threads.

1.
Change main to `async` and `await` for analysis result.

```
await MakeAnalysisRequest(imageFilePath);
```

And change the `MakeAnalysisRequest` method to be

```
static async Task MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath)
```

And the `Main` method to be

```
static async Task Main()
```

2.
or `Wait` for the result without changing `Main`

```
MakeAnalysisRequest(imageFilePath).Wait();
```

3.
You can also make the method can be accessed in sequence only

```
private static object sync = new object();
static string JsonPrint(string contentString, string imageFilePath)
{
    lock (sync)
    {
        //DO STUFF
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot await void

Comment: The original code always closes the file after use.  So it's external and `lock()` won't do anything. And you can't await here. I'm afraid we're down to 0 options.

Comment: Read carefully it uses async method without await so it's multiple threads against one file.

Comment: Thanks. I tried first option but instead of making main method as async, I created a new async method and called it from Main method. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no async void in my answer